# Why are external links not valid URLs?

Tags: uri, 10

I have a Drupal 10 intranet site on our school's internal network. I want to add a link to an intranet webpage on another server on the network. The url is similar to  "https://10.100.99.9/otherpage.php". But when I put it in a Link field I get an error that the field does not contain a valid url. The link is one of many links (external links, internal links, internal network links) that will end up in a list view.

Is there a way to add a link to another server on the same network?

Comment: This link works in a Drupal link field with external links allowed.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I have it set to External links only under Allowed Link Type.

Comment: Solution: I changed Allowed Link Type to Both internal and external links. That allowed the URL "https://10.100.99.9/otherpage.php". It would not let me add that link with External links only set.

Comment: It does work for me with "external links only" in Drupal v10.2

Comment: OK. I'm not sure why it isn't working for me. I am using the Field Formatter Class module. Maybe that is interfering somehow.